# swrast_dri.so amdgpu_query_sw_info error

Tags: drivers

when I run `glxgears`

```
"amdgpu_query_sw_info"
libGL error: dlopen /usr/lib64/dri/swrast_dri.so failed (/usr/lib64/dri/swrast_dri.so:     undefined symbol: amdgpu_query_sw_info)
```